# Can't get local sphinx-apidoc templates to work

Tags: python-sphinx, sphinx-apidoc

Re: Using [`sphinx-apidoc`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html) to automatically generate API reference from docstrings via the `autodoc` extension...

I copied the global `/site-packages/sphinx/templates/apidoc/package.rst_t` template to a local folder, and made a nonsense edit. When I built the API docs, the nonsense edit wasn't visible ie. the local templates didn't seem to override the global ones.

Here's my local `docs/source` directory:

```
|_ docs
   |_ source
      |_ templates
      |    package.rst_t
      |_ conf.py
      |_ index.rst
```

`conf.py` contains this directive:

```
templates_path = ['templates']
```

I built the API docs using this command:

```
sphinx-apidoc -e -M -f --templatedir=./templates -o ./source/autodoc ../myproject
```

Can anyone see what's going wrong?

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? It's not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: I would like to edit the local versions of the templates so I can change the way the docstrings are displayed. So for example the global `package.rst_t` template appends "package" to the name on line 19: `{{- [pkgname, "package"] | join(" ") | e | heading }}`. I would like to remove the word "package", like this: `{{- [pkgname | e | heading }}`.

Comment: When you issue the command, what is the current working directory?

Comment: Thanks @mzjn ! User error. Running from the `docs` directory, so putting `source` in the `--templatedir` path got local templates working (ie. `sphinx-apidoc -e -M -f --templatedir=./source/templates -o ./source/autodoc ../myproject`). PS. Do you happen to know if there's a way to edit templates for classes, functions etc? In `site-packages` for Sphinx there's `module.rst_t` and `package.rst_t` templates, but no equivalent (eg) `class.rst_t`..?

Comment: Currently there isn't a good way to do that. sphinx-apidoc generates `automodule` directives only. See also https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/6788, https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2897